# What are the PreferenceManager and SharedPreference classes used for in Android?

Tags: java, android

I've come across two classes being used in a tutorial on splash screens PreferenceManager and SharedPreferences. I didn't gain a great deal of knowledge about them from the tutorial though.

So can someone explain to me what both classes do or are used for?

Comment: They are used to store and retrieve the **settings** for your app. It's like having some variables stored in a file along with their values. These are in fact called **key/value pairs**.

Comment: Be advised; these values are lost when you uninstall the application. They are normally kept safe during an update; but 'due to some "unknown" problem, the data may get lost'

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Preferences** is an Android lightweight mechanism to store and retrieve    pairs 
of primitive data types (also called Maps, and Associative Arrays).

In each entry of the form  the key is a string and the value must be a primitive data type.

**WHEN WE NEED THEM:**

PREFERENCES are typically used to keep state information and shared data 
among several activities of an application.

Shared Preferences is the storage, in android, that you can use to store some basic things related to functionality, users' customization or its profile.

Suppose you want to save user's name in your app for future purposes. You cant save such a little thing in database, So you better keep it saved in your Preferences. Preferences is just like a file , from which you can retrieve value anytime in application's lifetime in a KEY-VALUE pair manner.

Take another example, If you use whatsapp, we have a wallpaper option there. How the application knows which image serves as wall-paper for you whenever you open your whatsapp. This information is stored in preferences. Whenever you clear data for any app, preferences are deleted.

**HOW TO USE THESE PREFERENCES :**

```
final int mode = Activity.MODE_PRIVATE; 
final String MYPREFS = "MyPreferences_001"; 

// create a reference to the shared preferences object 
SharedPreferences mySharedPreferences; 

// obtain an editor to add data to my SharedPreferences object 
SharedPreferences.Editor myEditor;

mySharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(MYPREFS, 0); 

// using this instance you can get any value saved.
 mySharedPreferences.getInt("backColor",Color.BLACK); // default value is BLACK set here
```

**EDITING SHARED PREFERENCES :**

```
myEditor = mySharedPreferences.edit(); 
//edit and commit
myEditor.putString("backColor", Color.RED); 
myEditor.commit() //very imp.
```

Comment: `You cant save such a little thing in database` No, I can

Answer (score 17):

From the Android Developer site:

> [PreferenceManager:](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceManager.html)
>
> Used to help create Preference hierarchies from activities or XML.
>
> [SharedPreferences:](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)
>
> Interface for accessing and modifying preference data returned by
>   getSharedPreferences(String, int). For any particular set of
>   preferences, there is a single instance of this class that all clients
>   share.

Put simply, `PreferenceManager` is normally used when you want to create a `PreferenceActivity` or load in some Preferences from an `.xml` file in your application with default values, and holds it's own referenced to `SharedPreferences`.

`SharedPreferences` is where you handle the storing and retrieving of **key/value pairs** that make up your preferences. So you can add variables with keys to retrieve the data later. This feeds into the `PreferenceManager` which can handle adding default values and setting up the default `SharedPreferences`.

You can use `SharedPreferences` throughout your application without needing to use `PreferenceManager`, but the opposite isn't strictly true.

Further reading:

- [PreferenceActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceActivity.html) (also [PreferenceFragment](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceFragment.html)), which uses
  `PreferenceManager` in the examples.
- Android [Data Storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref) which
  uses `SharedPreferences` (as well as other options).
- [Vogella article](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidFileBasedPersistence/article.html) on Android Persistence.
- [StackOverflow issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3624280/how-to-use-sharedpreferences-in-android-to-store-fetch-and-edit-values) on using `SharedPreferences` correctly.

Comment: This is a more concise answer to the original question than the accepted answer - thank you.

Answer (score 1):

As explained Artoo Detoo... Sharedpreferences kinda works like sessions in web development. you can use them to pass values from one activity to another and it stays that way as far as the app is in use except otherwise changed..

it is also use to user value (either after login or registration of the user). thats how much i can talk about it

Comment: so it lets the app no when switching activities that the user is logged in otherwise it would reset itself to being logged out once it changes activity? Or for another example, the user sets the music off for the app and wants the app to remember that this will handle it?

Comment: it never changes it value unless the user changes it...that is if the developer gives the user the power to... your second example answers it all..

Answer (score 1):

**SharedPreference** APIs are used to save key-value pairs. They store them in files and are private or public based on the mode you instantiate the SharedPreference object. They are used to store a small set of key-value pairs. This key here is of type String and the value can be any primitive type.

**PreferenceManager** is part of the Preference APIs. Preference API allows you to define a complete settings UI. This settings UI is an XML layout. You use a PreferenceManager to manage this Preference object's tree. It uses the SharedPreference APIs to store the various settings a user might change using that graphical layout you created.

Reference - ["Android Docs Training"](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html)